# select a SF2 choice option

Tags: silex

My code for my form ( i am using Silex):

```php
$test =  array(
                'Swedish Cars' => array(
                    'volvo' => 'Volvo',
                    'saab' => 'Saab',
                ),
                'German Cars' => array(
                    'mercedes' => 'Mercedes',
                    'audi' => 'Audi'
                )
            );

$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')
                ->add('title','text',array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Title of your Album'
                    )))
                ->add('description','textarea',array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'Describe your Album'
                    )))
                ->add('groups', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => $test,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'data-placeholder' => 'Add your Groups ...'
                    ),
                ))
```

The choices are defined as an multi-array, so I get `<option>` with `<optgropup>`. How can I enable in SF2, that some options are selected?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data` option:

```
->add('groups', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $test,
    'multiple' => true,
    'attr' => array(
        'data-placeholder' => 'Add your Groups ...',
    'data' => $selected_value
    ),
```

where `$selected_value` can be a single value like `'value_1'` or an simple array with multiple values `array('value_1', 'value_2')` to select.

Comment: thx, that did work, but the $selected_value can't be an associative array!

Comment: You can not use an associative array but a simple array - I have edited my answer above to make it a bit more clear.